# How do I tell pdflatex where to find a .600pk file

Tags: paths, kpathsea

I have a letter template `areletter.tex` file, which loads a style file called `areletter.cls`.    My template requires a seal in order for the letterhead to compile.   The seal file is `ucseal60.600pk` and the full path to this file is included in `areletter.cls`, in a line that looks like this:

\font\uc=/home/simon/LOCALSVN/latex/trunk/ucseal60.600pk

In spite of this line, the only way I can compile my letter is if I have a copy of  `ucseal60.600pk` in my `cwd`.   Since I obviously don't want to have copy the seal file to the `cwd` every time I write a letter, I'd like to include the full path to it in my `areletter.tex` file.    But I can't find anyway to tell the tex file where to find the seal file.    Could somebody please tell me what line would work?

Comment: Which compiler (engine) are you using?

Comment: tex can not read pk files, you need the tfm file

Comment: dvips (not tex) looks in PKFONTS path so by default you could put it in eg `~/texmf/fonts/pk/ljfour/`

Comment: it seems if maketextfm (probably accidentally) ends up, after a warning, inputting the tfm file (if it exists) if you try to load a pk, so you can use `\font\uc=ucseal60` which will directly access the tfm.